# Interactivity where are you gone?

Tags: java, charts, birt

I have been browsing around your many sites about BIRT and specially for Interactivity or scripting related subjects.

But (it would be sooo nice to live in a flawless world) trying to perform some examples (like this one http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/birt/chart/examples/api/interactivity/InteractivityCharts.java.htm) which is supposed to make interactive charts I get nothing ... well yes I get something : charts (very nice ones by the way ;p) but I have searched for the interactivity aaaaaand it's gone ... may be to the swimming pool or at the laundry but certainely not there ... If you want I can send you the code I used to display the charts or anything you'd like but I really need to make my charts interactives and feel quite helpless and distraught (I'd prefer dazed and confused ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right after declaring your IDeviceRenderer
you must 
idr.setProperty( IDeviceRenderer.UPDATE_NOTIFIER, anyclass that implements IUpdateNotifier );

Then you have plenty of documentations on
http://www.birt-exchange.org/documentation/BIRT_220/ChartJavadoc/chart/api/org/eclipse/birt/chart/device/IUpdateNotifier.html

And forever Google is your friend ^^

Comment: It is ugly to accept my own answer to my own question but that is the best answer I found to solve my problem :s

Answer (score 2):

The easiest path to interactivity for BIRT-based content is the Interactive Viewer.  Have a look at the specs here:  http://www.birt-exchange.com/be/products/birt-report-viewers/actuate-interactive-viewer/features/

Comment: Thank you for the link but I need specifically to render my charts as SWT component for an Eclipse RCP app'.
But thank you for the link !